# How can I best use a manpage tar ball? (untar + search + read)

Tags: linux, bash, manpage

During an offiline C programming exam, we only have access to a tarball of the latest man pages (https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/man-pages/).

The man pages installed on the system itself are outdated.

Is there a way to replace the systems current man pages with the given tar ball or make them more accessible, such that I can search through them and use `less` to read them?

Comment: Questions about using your UNIX system's included tools are better suited for our sister site [unix.se]. Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing code_ or tools exclusively for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just untar them and then point `man` at specific files. E.g:

```
$ cd man-pages-6.00
$ man man3/printf.3
```

This will open the man page in your pager.

You can also set the `MANPATH` environment variable to point to this location; then `man` will use it by default:

```
$ cd man-pages-6.00
$ export MANPATH=$PWD
$ man printf
```

This will *replace* the system man pages, so that running `man` for a command not included in the tar archive will fail:

```
$ man ls
No manual entry for ls
```

You can get the best of both worlds by telling `man` to search the unpacked tar archive *first*, and then search the system man pages:

```
$ cd man-pages-6.00
$ export MANPATH=$PWD:
$ man ls
```

That trailng `:` in `MANPATH=$PWD:` means "use the default path".

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that the man command hat this capability. Thank you!